# ventana modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, modal

Hace tiempo vengo desarrollando un porfolio web online según las especificaciones de un curso. hace poco decidí colocar en la navbar un dropdown  de bootstrap con las opciones de configuración e iniciar sesión.
**El problema** es que la opción de iniciar sesión es una ventana modal de bootstrao que quería proceder a modificarlo y transformarlo en una ventana de iniciar sesión. pero al presionar el botón hace la animación de opacity en el fondo, pero nunca aparece la ventana modal. ¿Cual podría ser el problema?

**Mi código HTML:**

```css
nav{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #131313;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 99;
  display: flex;
}
nav .navbar{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
}
.navbar .logo a{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
}
nav .navbar .links{
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
nav .navbar .links li{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 14px;
}
nav .navbar .links li a{
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.links i{
 margin-right: 5px;
}
.navbar .nav-links .sidebar-logo{
  display: none;
}
.navbar .bx-menu{
  display: none;
}
.imgcont {
  margin-inline-end: auto;
}
.imgcont img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.dropdown {
  margin-inline-start: auto;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.nav-links {
    justify-content: center;
    margin-inline-end: auto;
}
.btn-primary {
  --bs-btn-bg: #fd950d00;
  --bs-btn-hover-bg: #0b5dd700;
  --bs-btn-border-color: #0d6dfd00;
  --bs-btn-hover-border-color: #0a57ca00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Developer</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="Imagenes/Icono-Pesataña.ico">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class=" navbar">
        <i class='bx bx-menu'></i>
        <div class="imgcont">
          <img src="Imagenes/000.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="nav-links">
          <div class="sidebar-logo">
           <i class='bx bx-x' ></i>
          </div>
          <ul class="links">
           <li>
              <a href="#hero"><i class="bi bi-house-fill"></i>INICIO</a>
            </li>
            <li>
             <a href="#sobre-mi"><i class="bi bi-person-circle"></i>SOBRE MÍ</a>
            </li>
           <li>
             <a href="#experiencia"><i class="bi bi-cup-hot-fill"></i>EXPERIENCIA</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#proyectos"><i class="bi bi-terminal-fill"></i>PROYECTOS</a>
           </li>
           <li>
              <a href="#contacto"><i class="bi bi-envelope-at-fill"></i>CONTACTO</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown d-flex">
        <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
           <img src="Imagenes/Icono-Pesataña.ico" alt="" class="rounded-circle" width="32" height="32">
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
           <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuracion</a></li>
           <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>         
           <li>
            <button type="button" class="btnsesion btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@getbootstrap">Iniciar sesión</button>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h1>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                      <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                      </div>
                      <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Desde ya gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: La línea 26 de tu HTML tiene un problema hay un `</i`>` que sobra. Partamos por corregir eso

Comment: ok, ya corregí eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El DIV del modal dentro de la etiqueta NAV esta causando conflicto, para evitar esto es conveniente dejar el div del modal afuera del nav por ejemplo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Developer</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="Imagenes/Icono-Pesataña.ico">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class=" navbar">
        <i class='bx bx-menu'></i>
        <div class="imgcont">
          <img src="Imagenes/000.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="nav-links">
          <div class="sidebar-logo">
           <i class='bx bx-x' ></i>
          </div>
          <ul class="links">
           <li>
              <a href="#hero"><i class="bi bi-house-fill"></i>INICIO</a>
            </li>
            <li>
             <a href="#sobre-mi"><i class="bi bi-person-circle"></i>SOBRE MÍ</a>
            </li>
           <li>
             <a href="#experiencia"><i class="bi bi-cup-hot-fill"></i>EXPERIENCIA</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#proyectos"><i class="bi bi-terminal-fill"></i>PROYECTOS</a>
           </li>
           <li>
              <a href="#contacto"><i class="bi bi-envelope-at-fill"></i>CONTACTO</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown d-flex">
        <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
           <img src="Imagenes/Icono-Pesataña.ico" alt="" class="rounded-circle" width="32" height="32">
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
           <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuracion</a></li>
           <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>         
           <li>
            <button type="button" class="btnsesion btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@getbootstrap">Iniciar sesión</button>
           
           </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
    </nav>
//mover aquí
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h1>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                      <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                      </div>
                      <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. :) funciono perfectamente.